# Postback Problems by using UpdatePanel

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel, master-pages

I have Used Asp UpdatePanel On Master Page To stop postback. But now it's Create problem on other pages, such as data fetching in gridview on button click.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="updatePanle1">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder1"  runat="server">
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: Add `Triggers` for all those controls which would cause postback.

Answer (score 0):

try this code.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            GridviewBind();
        }
}


<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatepnl" runat="server">
   <ContentTemplate>
        ---Put Your Grid View Code---
    </ContentTemplate>
       <Triggers>
            <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnSubmit" />      
        </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding `Triggers` in your `UpdatePanel` desgin code here to stop the other events causing postback including button clicks and others. Try something like this :

```
 <Triggers>        
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Button1" EventName="clickEvent" />    
 </Triggers>
```

You can also try using `PostBackTrigger` instead of `AsyncPostBackTrigger` here incase if it doesnt work out as expected.

```
<Triggers>        
        <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="Button1" EventName="clickEvent" />    
 </Triggers>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: but trigers i have to use on every page there is no short method for whole applicacation

Comment: That is one of the demerits of using `UpdatePanel`. There is probably no one spot solution for this as far as I know. This shouldn't be a lot of work unless you have loads of controls.

Answer (score 0):

We don't normally use the update panel just to prevent the whole asp.net site from re-loading page / posting back. Client controls (jquery) would still be the best fit. But if you're really curious you might want to grind time learning the lessons in this MSDN link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398864%28v=vs.140%29.aspx